# Alfresco V5.2 - How to get current page url in a live search webscript

Tags: url, search, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts, livesearch

In the search part, I need the search to be limited only to the current directory or location of the user. Suppose, if I am in a directory on a specific site, just search from there down the directory tree.

To which I am trying to modify the **live-search.lib.js** file that is in **alfresco-share-services-5.2.f.jar**.

So I want to fetch the current page URL which I will be using to filter out the search result.

Any other suggestions to achieve this specific folder search, are Welcomed.

Thank You.

Comment: why can't you achieve this in getting the current folder path you are in?

Comment: that what I am trying to do, but I am not able to find the correct folder path. could you please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ScriptNode API. You have to find the doc(by using findNode method)

Then you can use `document.displayPath` to get path.

-Arjun